# How to format xAxis label as date for each value in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a simple line chart. As you can see data is formatted so that the first value in array is date (year - month), and then there is a value. I can change the format of date if necessary but data will generally always have a single value for each month in ascending order up to current month.

Is it possible to format chart so that bottom axis has labels for date (year + month)? Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ivan-topi/pen/QWwqaXw) of my working example and here is the [original Highchart example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) if needed.

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        ["2018-10", 18],
        ["2018-11", 16],
        ["2018-12", 21],
        ["2019-01", 22],
        ["2019-02", 22],
        ["2019-03", 20],
        ["2019-04", 22],
        ["2019-05", 24],
        ["2019-06", 25],
        ["2019-07", 31],
        ["2019-08", 35],
        ["2019-09", 33],
        ["2019-10", 35],
        ["2019-11", 35],
        ["2019-12", 35]
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

This is what I am aiming for 
[image]

If I can easier do this in a different library I am open to suggestions.

Comment: there is way to do it custom code, depends on your data, if your data is dynamic or static, you can use custom categories for xAxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this way, using type category will give the xaxis of series

```
 xAxis: {
   type: 'category',
   labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            var str = this.value.split('-');
            return str[1]+'<br>'+ str[0];
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter() {

                // get data from series, "this.value" is a key for each array
                var currentData = this.chart.userOptions.series[0].data[this.value];

                // split "2018-10" into array and return each on new line
                var currentData = currentData[0].split('-');
                return currentData[1] + '<br>' + currentData[0];

            }
        }

    },

  series: [
    {
      data: [
        ["2018-10", 18],
        ["2018-11", 16],
        ["2018-12", 21],
        ["2019-01", 22],
        ["2019-02", 22],
        ["2019-03", 20],
        ["2019-04", 22],
        ["2019-05", 24],
        ["2019-06", 25],
        ["2019-07", 31],
        ["2019-08", 35],
        ["2019-09", 33],
        ["2019-10", 35],
        ["2019-11", 35],
        ["2019-12", 35]
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```